# Volume Mixer keeps showing up

Tags: windows-10, volume-mixer

When I leave my PC on overnight sometimes I come back to opened volume mixer. Doesn't happen all the time but enough times for me to notice it. Does anyone know why this could happen?

Specs:  Windows 10, i7 5820k GTX 970. I have a mechanical keyboard that does not have a volume knob

Comment: More info is needed here: Which OS are we talking? Hardware config? Do you by any chance have a keyboard with a volume up/down?

Comment: Sorry. Windows 10, i7 5820k GTX 970.
I have a mechanical keyboard that does not have a volume knob

Comment: That info needs to be included in the question.

Comment: Is any audio channel muted while it should not be? Many years ago my friend's audio card would auto-mute some channels in response to strong electromagnetic noise from a phone line in the vicinity of the speakers cable (it was an old phone with a crank and electric generator). Your driver may react to this behavior and open a mixer. It's probably not it, still I wanted to share the story. :)

Comment: I also have a digital audio channel which is not muted. Still, thanks for your suggestion